# Carino, carinissimo, che carino!

Tags: single-words

Penso abbiate visto tutti la pubblicità di [Treccani](https://www.google.it/search?q=pubblicit%C3%A0%20treccani%20carino&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=pubblicita%20treccani%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.6682j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)
in  cui, sostanzialmente, si invita i giovani ad usare un maggior numero di vocaboli, e quindi  a fare un miglior uso della lingua italiana.

Qual è il termine, se esiste,  che definisce un linguaggio caratterizzato da un uso limitato dei vocaboli disponibili? (in sostanza quello che Treccani ci sta dicendo).

Comment: "Carinissimo": un superlativo di un diminutivo! Veramente voi italiani siete molto divertenti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Lessico povero", "vocabolario limitato". È quello che si legge nelle valutazioni di certi cómpiti scolastici.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Un singolo termine non mi viene in mente, puoi tranquillamente dire che la persona della pubblicità ha un vocabolario limitato.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie, @egreg! Sono orgogliosa di essere connazionale del top user di TEX SE, ahahah!

Comment: Benvenuta! Non capisco questo "puoi" nella tua risposta.

Comment: @Charo "puoi" nel senso che si può fare, non ci sono problemi se utilizzi "vocabolario limitato", è un'espressione che si sente dire normalmente in italiano, non è "strana". Spero di aver chiarito il tuo dubbio...

Comment: Ma allora sarebbe "puoi tranquillamente dire" (non "direi"), no?

Comment: @Charo, certo, è stato un errore di battitura, brava, l'ho corretto!

Answer (score 1):

Non credo che esista il termine che cerchi, che dovrebbe avere una connotazione leggermente negativa.

Una parola *simile* è **microlingua**.

> /mi·cro·lìn·gua/ sostantivo femminile
>
> Linguaggio settoriale molto semplificato sul piano morfosintattico e privo di connotazioni stilistiche.

Però una microlingua è tipicamente oligosemica, o addirittura monosemica (ogni parola ha pochi, o un solo, significato molto preciso). Nel caso di chi dispone di un vocabolario limitato invece si assiste al fenomeno contrario, quello della polisemia, in cui poche parole servono a descrivere una quantità di significati (un po' come succede con la parola *coso*), e non di rado il linguaggio viene supplementato da gesti o espressioni.

In genere chi parla una microlingua lo fa perché è in una situazione che lo richiede, e dispone di un vocabolario normalmente *più ampio* della media. Per esempio è il caso degli avvocati o dei medici.

Si potrebbe usare il termine **gergo**, ma di solito un gergo contiene parole non esistenti nella lingua "madre".

Come aggettivo per un linguaggio potrei azzardare *colloquiale* (anche questo però non è molto soddisfacente).

Se arriva ad essere un vero e proprio disturbo, il termine politicamente corretto è *disturbo specifico del linguaggio*; una volta si chiamava *oligofasia*.